# Problems with DefaultCacheServer when deploying Coherence REST

Tags: java, rest, deployment, oracle-coherence

First of all, im a newbie in Java programming, since i'm actually a PHP Programmer not a Java Programmer. And my team want to build a system using PHP, and Coherence REST.

The first time, i tried to deploy it using using Glassfish, according the article from this url http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22839/rest_deploy.htm#BABBIIEE and i get this error "Trying to upload an illegal war archive. Make sure the archive file contains the descriptor file web.xml."

After that, i try to deploy manually according the article from this url http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24290_01/coh.371/e22839/rest_example.htm#CHDBDGHG
And i got this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tangosol/net/DefaultCacheServer. Could not find the main class: com.tangosol.net.DefaultCacheServer.  Program will exit.

Is there anyone who can help me to solve my problem?

Any information will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My bad, i already found out the solution. I have the wrong environment variables. Newbie mistake. thanks guys